# How to get textfield value in App Inventor without form submission?

Tags: textbox, app-inventor

I want to know the event in blocks section using which the entered text value can be obtained without a form submission through button.

Let's say user inputs text in mobile phone through keyboard and presses enter. In this case I want some event to trigger and get the value that user entered.

There are 2 events available like `lostfocus` and `gotfocus`.
Will these work? Or is there any other good approach for getting text value on pressing enter?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such event like `OnEnterPressed` available in MIT App Inventor and the events `LostFocus` and `GotFocus` will not work in this case.

What you currently can do is

1. use a button and use the `Button.Click` event, or
2. create your own custom keyboard, see also [this example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/8lKN6B00wYY/WptnS5dkEgAJ)

Currently there is a limitation for [App Inventor extensions](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html), which only can be used for non-visible components. Later as soon as also visible components are doable, then you could write your own textbox extension and add an event yourself.

---

Edit concerning the new question in the comments about different screens:

**Use different screens wisely**
Before starting to create another screen, first you should think about *is it really necessary?* See also [Building apps with many screens](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/manyscreens.html) and [SteveJG's post about advantages/disadvantages](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/ka-LS7wmWxs/wRbs70x2BgAJ), because **in only one screen you also can use vertical arrangements to simulate different screens**, just set the arrangements to visible = true/false as needed...

Comment: thanks for your response,@Taifun. If I create a custom keyboard, how can I add it it many screens i have. For example I have 10 pages and I want to user to enter a text in all the screens? I don't want to repeat the code..

Comment: actually this is a new question, you might want to *ask a new question* next time... for now see my updated answer and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a `Clock` component that monitors the `TextBox1.Text`. When it triggers, it checks if the `TextBox1.Text` has changed and saves it to a variable. When it triggers again, it compares the variable with `TextBox1.Text`. After the user finishes typing, the variable and `TextBox1.Text` will be equal and then you can trigger the event like you eanted when the user pressed Enter.

Hope this helps!